# Are drivers available for NVIDIA GEFORCE 740M?

Tags: drivers, nvidia-geforce

Does Ubuntu 16.04.2 support NVIDIA graphics adapter 740M? Are there any drivers available?

Comment: Yes, it is supported and drivers are available.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.04.2 perfectly supports the NVIDIA graphics. There are drivers available in the Ubuntu 16.04 repositories and to install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers for the GEFORCE 740M open a terminal and execute the following command : `sudo apt install nvidia-375 nvidia-prime` Reboot the operating system to activate and make use of the freshly installed NVIDIA drivers.

Additional information : Every Ubuntu system comes with the open source `nouveau` drivers pre-installed and if you don't play demanding games or use other applications which need a higher graphics hardware performance, you don't need to install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers. The package `nvidia-prime` is only necessary when the notebook has NVIDIA Optimus support.

Comment: How did you know which version of Nvidia to install? 375  isn't working on 17.10, 384 too

Comment: @DmitryMagas' Hi Dmitry, are you running Ubuntu in a Wayland session ? In case you do, please read [Ubuntu 17.10 on Wayland - (How) can I install the NVIDIA drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967955/ubuntu-17-10-on-wayland-how-can-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/968015#968015). `nvidia-384` are the latest stable drivers from the NVIDIA long-lived branch and available in the Ubuntu repositories, thats's why I chose them - they are the recommended version to install currently. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, the propriety driver from Nvidia, version 340.107 works best. It can be installed using the Additional Drivers tab from the Software and Updates.