# Ubuntu 17.10 on Wayland - (How) can I install the NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 17.10

I have a NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1060 graphics card - how do I have to install the NVIDIA drivers properly in Ubuntu 17.10?
Is it the same procedure as in 17.04 or does the fact that Ubuntu 17.10 uses the Wayland session by default change something?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The proprietary NVIDIA drivers are still not supported under Wayland, yet. When you want to install and use the NVIDIA drivers, you have to select **Ubuntu on Xorg** on the GDM login screen to enter the **X session**. Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers by executing these commands in a terminal :

- To install the NVIDIA drivers, execute `sudo apt install nvidia-384`.
- Additionally you can force the GDM login screen to use Xorg by default.
  To achieve this, just execute `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.
  Remove the character `#` from the line `# WaylandEnable=false`.
  Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save that change.
- Restart the Ubuntu operating system, execute `sudo reboot`.

The installation process did not change since Ubuntu 17.04 - and on X everything is the same. The current situation might change soon, because there is already some promising work in progress to get the proprietary NVIDIA drivers running in a Wayland session - maybe in Ubuntu 18.04 it'll work.

Find more details about the current development status from the developers on GitHub :
[The EGL External Platform interface](https://github.com/NVIDIA/eglexternalplatform)  | [The EGLStream-based Wayland external platform](https://github.com/NVIDIA/egl-wayland)

Answer (score 2):

To add to the cl-netbox answer the default kernel version for me was the lowlatency on 17.10, it started working for me after switching to a generic kernel (I had to install the kernel headers first then reinstalled the nvidia driver on the generic kernel)