# GIMP returns Segmentation fault in fresh 17.10 installation

Tags: 17.10, gimp

After a fresh 17.10 installation, GIMP (when installed from the Ubuntu repositories) returns a `Segmentation fault` and does not start. Things I have unsuccessfully tried so far:

1. Both Wayland and Xorg sessions.
2. Deleting/creating the `.gimp-2.8` folder.
3. Installing from an alternative ppa.
4. Running GIMP as a different user.

For some reason though, the snap version seems to work fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In a fresh and up to date installed system of Ubuntu 17.10 running with Wayland, **`gimp version 2.8.20-1` is installed from Ubuntu's repositories and it works for me**, at least the basic functions. (There are bugs, for example the general screeenshot via the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button works, but not gimp's screenshot option.)

[image]

Maybe your `gimp` will work after update & upgrade,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Otherwise I suggest that you start `gimp` from a terminal window and check if there is some specific error output.

---

**Edit:** The original poster, @GiorgosKapetanakis, found this to be an issue with nvidia (one of many issues with nvidia proprietary drivers in Wayland).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also have gimp version 2.8.20-1 installed from the official Ubuntu repositories and it **does not work**. Also, all my packages are up-to-date. I have tried running GIMP from terminal and the only output is `Segmentation fault`.

Comment: Something critical must be different. Have you installed some other graphical programs, maybe some programs via PPA or deb files or tarballs? Something must be different from my installed 17.10 system. Is your system standard Ubuntu, or one of the community flavours (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu)? Is your system created via upgrading from an iso file prior to the released 17.10 Ubuntu iso file? What graphics card is there in your computer? And what graphics driver?

Comment: Strange behavior! Your reply got me thinking and did some more tests: First of all, I cleanly installed the standard (after-release) 17.10 Ubuntu (not *ubuntu) iso, no third party ppa's or deb files/tarballs etc. But I have a hybrid intel/nvidia optimus card (my system is a ThinkPad T430u). I logged in with nvidia (with proprietary driver, in xorg) and voilà, Gimp started normally! After that it seems to be working normally even with intel on either wayland or xorg! Still, I cannot explain this...

Comment: This rings a bell: I have seen reports about issues with nvidia (with proprietary drivers in Wayland). See for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/967955/ubuntu-17-10-on-wayland-how-can-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers I'm glad you found a way to get around it :-)