# Ubuntu 16.04 installation stalls on splash screen

Tags: dual-boot

Ubuntu stalls during installation.

I created a USB Bootable media, using Rufus 2.18, of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

- Selected GPT for UEFI
- Selected ISO

Tested the bootable media on another laptop, it works.

I have a Dell Inspirion 15-5577
i7-7700I-Q

- Disabled hibernate
  powercfg /h off
- Partition
  shrink Windows, created a 381 gb space on harddrive
- Disabled secure boot in the BIOS

From Windows 10
  - Settings
  - Update & security
  - Recovery
  - Advanced startup
  - restart now

- Use a device
- USB Storage Device
- Select F12 Boot Options during boot
- UEFI Options
- USB1 - UEFI OS

Options:
* Try Ubuntu without installing
Install Ubuntu

I've tried both.  They both stall.
I've left the machine stalled for several hours on both.

How do I troubleshoot from here?

Comment: Where exactly has the process stalled at?  Did it complete downloading a bunch of files?  Did it complete asking for your timezone information?  Did Ubuntu get to the point of asking you to reboot?

Comment: no.  I just updated the title with "on splash screen"

Comment: OK - This would indicate to me, that you had completed the install process and were in a reboot (since you passed through the "try Ubuntu..." menus.  I think that this question becomes a duplicate of a much referenced question....[https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)  Do not be confused by the 'black' in the title, but look for the section "Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time"

Comment: Yes!  The NVIDIA graphics card.  I changed 'quiet / splash' to 'nomodeset' and it booted.   Am attempting to install it now.  Thanks

Comment: You should be informed that 17.10 uses wayland by default, and that wayland will not work with nvidia drivers at this time.  Please see [https://askubuntu.com/questions/967955/ubuntu-17-10-on-wayland-how-can-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967955/ubuntu-17-10-on-wayland-how-can-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)