# I cant install any Nvidia Drivers at all (white flashing text behind a black screen)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.10

I'm new to Ubuntu and linux in general, but I know a few things. I've tried doing basically everything I've seen online: videos, similar questions in here, etc.

I first tried using Additional Drivers and installed the proprietary driver (`nvidia-384`) and once I did, I rebooted and I got a black screen with a flashing white text. So, I've uninstalled all nvidia drivers by using (`apt-get purge nvidia*`) and kept trying, and doing the same process over and over again with every driver showing under additional drivers. Not only have I used the Additional Drivers, but I've manually tried doing it in terminal, and nothing worked. Any suggestions? Thanks. Oh and I'm also running Ubuntu 17.10.

Specs:

- CPU: AMD A10 7600
- GPU: Nvida GTX 750ti
- Memory: 8gb

Here's what my Additional Drivers look like:
[image]

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/967955/ubuntu-17-10-on-wayland-how-can-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: didnt work :/ ugh