# Ubuntu 18.04 Installer Crashing on XPS 15 9570/9575

Tags: 18.04, xps, ubiquity

The Ubiquity installer crashes a few seconds after the partition stage.

Comment: Have you tried tailing syslog? Do you receive any errors? Please [edit] your post to provide further information. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this problem, then you are experiencing [Bug #1751252](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1751252). I know the issue is meant to happen on XPS 9560 and the errors aren't the same but I fixed it using the same patch.

Before you begin, make sure you do all the partitioning BEFORE opening the installer.

Then I used the patch from the answer below, copied from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033179/ubuntu-18-04-installer-crashes-on-dell-xps-15-9560#).

====

...there is a [patch](https://code.launchpad.net/~azzar1/ubiquity/+git/ubiquity/+merge/345056) you can use as a workaround...

1. Boot your 18.04 Live ISO
2. Select <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd>
3. Before you start the Ubiquity installer, open a Terminal window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>)
4. Execute the following commands in the Terminal to download and apply the patch

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads

   wget https://code.launchpad.net/~azzar1/ubiquity/+git/ubiquity/+merge/345056/+preview-diff/831305/+files/preview.diff --output-document ubiquity.patch

   sudo cp /usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/misc.py /usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/misc.py.original

   sudo patch /usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/misc.py ubiquity.patch
   ```
5. Start the installer by clicking on the Ubiquity icon, and it should now allow you to proceed through the installation

Comment: This was the bug that I encountered as well. I followed the [workaround described in the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1751252/comments/14) which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure fast-boot is disabled in Bios.

On power on press the appropriate key for your motherboard to get into Bios.
Check your motherboard / system vendors website or google for the key for Bios if you do not already know it.