# Installation fail - Lenovo Y700-15ISK

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, lenovo

I have Lenovo Y700-15ISK, specs here:
https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo...-tb-hdd/specs/

no modifications, Windows 10 on SSD.

I wanted to install xubuntu for web development purposes, on the 1TB HDD(dual-boot with win10). Updated BIOS and graphic drivers, done backup, created bootable USB with latest Xubuntu x64 .iso, turned off UEFI and FastBoot in BIOS, you know, usual stuff.

This is what i get when choosing eighter "install" or "try Xubuntu without install" options:

[error log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMsNS.jpg)

Any ideas?

Comment: review the bios setup. raid hdd seemd to be avctivated.

Comment: Hi Spoderman4 - your link takes me to a 'page not found' . Found the specs here https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-ideapad-y700/specs/ and it might be an nVidia graphics problem. Take a look at the answer here and see if it fixes the issue as it did for M. Plyer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043842/running-ubuntu-via-live-usb-error-on-dell-xps-15-9560#comment1701528_1043842

Comment: Actually, @cmak.fr seems to recognise the problem from your error log screenshot, so recommend trying that first. Not everything's an nVidia issue :)

Comment: Not sure that you need to turn off UEFI to install any recent Ubuntu flavours. As long as you make sure that you boot the USB in UEFI mode, then if Windows is already using UEFI, you want your Xubuntu to be booting in that same mode too. You can usually press a key when you startup (f12 on a Dell i own, f9 on an HP - not sure about Lenovo) that takes you to a one time startup menu that let's you choose to boot the stick in UEFI or Legacy mode.