# Dual Booting Ubuntu along with Windows 10

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

I have been trying to install the Ubuntu 16_04 version on my laptop dell inspiron 5577. Also tried installing 18_04 version. Both of them possess different errors.

The 16_04 version while installing through a USB drive, stops as soon as the ubuntu logo pops up at the beginning of the installation.

In the 18_04 version, the installation is successful however while booting, after we select ubuntu, the screen goes black and nothing happens ahead.

Laptop has got a SSD of 128GB, and by default it was MBR partitioned. The above two issues occurred while it was MBR partitioned.

Later I deleted thr partitions and installed the windows 10 using A usb drive which had windows 10 GPT partioned. Hence, Now my laptop has GPT partitioning. Windows 10 installation was successful after GPT partitioning in the SSD. I again tried installing both the versions of ubuntu using the alongside windows installation option. Now, the ubuntu(18_04) got installed on the 1TB HDD but it has got the same above error. I tried installing 16_04 version, however the same error again!

The error reads as "(sdc) no cache ...." and Some error of acpi.

PC Configuration, SSD :128 GB HDD :1TB Ram: 8GB Graphics Card :Nvidia GTX 1050 4GB Processor: Intel i5 7th Gen Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: Did you change UEFI from RAID to AHCI? Turn off Windows fast start-up? Update UEFI from Dell and SSD firmware?  Use nomodeset to boot initially and once installed add the proprietary nVidia driver only from Ubuntu repository or related ppa? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2386049 Dell Inspiron 7566
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342359 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043842/running-ubuntu-via-live-usb-error-on-dell-xps-15-9560

Comment: Installed it in VmWare at last.