# No GRUB and further issues after Ubuntu 18.04 install on Dell XPS 15 9560

Tags: grub2, nvidia, 18.04, dell, xps

I have just done a clean install (wiping the disk to remove windows) of Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell XPS 15 9560, after updating ubiquity to avoid a bug as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033179/ubuntu-18-04-installer-crashes-on-dell-xps-15-9560). Unfortunately after the installer finished it freezed after me accepting the reboot (could be the cause for the GRUB problem?), so I had to restart it by holding the power button.

After reboot, GRUB does not show up as usual but instead Ubuntu boots directly, which is very odd.

Then, after the login screen, I just see the cursor on a plain background. Now this is probably an issues with the  Nvidia drivers, which I would like to solve either

- by adding `nouveau.modeset=0` to boot parameters - can not do because GRUB does not show up
- or by installing Nvidia drivers similar to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030060/freeze-after-login-ubuntu-18-04) - can not do because the machine is not connected to Internet after installation.

Additionally, errors like `soft lockup - CPU stuck` or `task ... blocked for more than 120 seconds` keep popping up:
[image: soft lockup - CPU stuck]
[image: task ... blocked for more than 120 seconds]

Can anybody suggest a way how I could finally achieve a working Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to solve the issue directly but I achieved a well running Ubuntu installation using a respun ISO, see [JackHack96's GitHub](https://github.com/JackHack96/dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin).
Useful tips for getting it to run well can be found in [tomwwright's gist](https://gist.github.com/tomwwright/f88e2ddb344cf99f299935e1312da880).

Answer (score 0):

Hold Shift for 3 seconds after turning the system on. The GRUB should appear. Then press E and type `nomodeset` before `quiet splash` and press Ctrl+X.

Comment: By "after turning the system on", do you mean right after pressing the power button or after Ubuntu has already booted up? I tried and it had no effect, I just see the Dell logo and then Ubuntu boots up.