# Installer crashed when trying to install Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I keep getting this error message when i tried installing UBUNTU 18.04...installer crashed..please fix.does it have something with upgrading ubiquity?...am already confused

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Ubuntu 18.04 Installer crashes on Dell XPS 15 9560](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033179/ubuntu-18-04-installer-crashes-on-dell-xps-15-9560). To summarize: 
You are experiencing Bug #1751252.

There are two options to fix this:

Option 1: Install a newer fixed version of ubiquity

Boot your 18.04 Live ISO
Select Try Ubuntu
Before you start the Ubiquity installer, open a Terminal window (CTRL-ALT-T)
Execute the following commands in the terminal to upgrade Ubiquity:

`sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubiquity`

Then start Ubiquity from the desktop.

Option 2: Apply a patch to ubiquity

Boot your 18.04 Live ISO
Select Try Ubuntu
Before you start the Ubiquity installer, open a Terminal window (CTRL-ALT-T)
Execute the following commands in the Terminal to download and apply the patch:

```
cd ~/Downloads

wget https://code.launchpad.net/~azzar1/ubiquity/+git/ubiquity/+merge/345056/+preview-diff/831305/+files/preview.diff --output-document ubiquity.patch

sudo cp /usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/misc.py /usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/misc.py.original

sudo patch /usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/misc.py ubiquity.patch
```

Start the installer by clicking on the Ubiquity icon, and it should now allow you to proceed through the installation.

Note: this is just an edited version of the first answer from the link I gave.

Check out the link for more answers

Comment: sudo apt update gives errors.....for option 2 i didnt get it...am i to type wget https://code.launchpad.net/~azzar1/ubiquity/+git/ubiquity/+merge/345056/+preview-diff/831305/+files/preview.diff --output-document ubiquity.patch in the terminal after cd~/ Download

Comment: What errors does sudo apt update give? It shouldn’t be giving any...

Comment: ok it worked now...please what next..it also said 434 packages can be upgraded

Comment: sudo apt install ubiquity

Comment: 0 upgraded , 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 434 not upgraded

Comment: Then try Option 2 (the patch)

Comment: after i cd~/ Download...what next? am i to type this "wget https://code.launchpad.net/~azzar1/ubiquity/+git/ubiquity/+merge/345056/+preview-diff/831305/+files/preview.diff --output-document ubiquity.patch"

Comment: Yes, type that command

Comment: i will get back to you

Comment: Sure. Just remember to type those commands one by one. If it doesn’t work, shut down and reboot the computer

Comment: Otherwise,  try the other answers on the given link. If all that doesn’t work, make a new installation media

Comment: error 404 not found when i type it

Comment: cannot write to ubiquity.patch

Comment: So the file is missing. Try other answers on link or recreate installation media

Comment: Hold on the link works for me... connect to WiFi I believe that’s your issue