# "Installer crashed" while installing ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XP laptop, but it seems to be working?

Tags: system-installation, dell, crash

I tried installing Ubuntu on my new Dell XPS laptop today, and somewhere near the end of the installation procedure, I got the message saying the installer crashed and that I would be able to send a report afterwards.

I googled the issue, and turns out that it's not something uncommon with Dell XPS laptops and ubuntu.

For example, I found this issue: [Installer crashed when trying to install Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150797/installer-crashed-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu-18-04)

Okay, seems like it's easily fixed. I was planning to reboot and try the suggested steps in the first answer to that question. However... when I rebooted, it didn't boot from my installation medium, but to my surprise it booted the freshly installed Ubuntu.

Now I wonder... will this installation be stable? Or will it be unstable due to missing parts, and would it be best to simply format my disk and start the installation over from scratch?

Comment: You'll need to read the messages & installation logs to know if the installation is trusthworthy or not. We cannot know as we don't have the details. If you filed a bug report, you'll be able to know from that too. Most installer crash reports I see filed show a trustworthy installation (with only grub install failed or like issue), but without details as to what the issue is, we can only guess.

Comment: Fair point @guiverc . Is there a way to do a post-install installation-check? 
I read something about a system-interity-check package, but I wasn't able to install it with apt. It seems like it was removed from the repo?

Comment: maybe look at`debsums` - *tool for verification of installed package files against MD5 checksums*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several of my colleagues (also with similar Dell XPS notebooks) experienced exactly the same error during installation. The apparently it has something to do with the Nvidia GPU's in our systems.

My colleagues did not report any problems (yet), but I myself have experienced 2 problems that at first seemed unrelated, but after a lot of investigation I found explanations that expicitely said that these were linked to an incomplete install of the OS.

### So, YES: Even though the installation will appear to work just fine at first, there will still be loose ends. I would strongly advise reinstalling from scratch.